# Need help getting subreports to work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

We have the primary report that uses a stored procedure to pull from one table in our database and want to add a subreport that would show the history of the cases listed in the primary report.  Basically, the primary report looks like the following (sort of)

[CID] | [Status] | [Type] | etc....

The [CID] above can be used to pull up all of the events relating to the individual [CID]s and so we want the final product to look kind of like this:

[CID] | [Status] | [Type] | etc....

```
 [+] <- click here to see the event history
```

I've created the subreport report (rdlc) file and the stored procedure that would supply the event history based on the [CID], but adding it to the primary report isn't working the way that we would expect.  We've added the subreport via right-clicking on the primary report and opting to insert a subreport.  We've given the new object the name of the corresponding rdlc file.  We've made sure to add that the subreport's rdlc file is expecting a parameter for the [CID].  All that it will do is display the following error at the very end of the primary report (not after each [CID] in the report):  "Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'subreportname', located at subreportname.rdlc. Please check the log files for more information."

We've tried placing the subreport directly below the primary report's information, in a rectangle directly below the primary report's information, placed the rectangle in a cell that is part of the primary report's information and then placed the subreport in it, both as part of the same group and as a different group.

I'd love to look at those log files if I could figure out where they are located (any ideas?), but at this point we are just spinning our wheels and need some direction.  Internet searches have shown many posts about doing subreports in Visual Studio 2010, but those are worthless considering the changes between VS2010 and VS2013.  Very few search results provide anything that have to do with Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the sub reports parameters setup correctly?  These should probably be populated using the dataset from the primary report.

Also, if it is only showing once you probably have it's location wrong.  If you have a list showing a bunch of CID entries it should be within that list.  Or table cell, etc...

Comment: I'll update my question to answer, but in short I've tried adding the subreport 'box' in several different places on the primary report, both right below but still on the report to inside a rectangle placed on the report or trying to place it directly in a cell in the same and in different groups.

Comment: Usually when I get that error it has to do with parameters not being set correctly.  Sorry couldn't help more.

Comment: I don't suppose you know where the log files that it mentions in the error are located, do you?